# Selenium Webdriver (Java) - exclude a particular tag from the css selector

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How can I exclude a tag from the css selector. I have a html code below:

```
<div class="info">
    <h3>Test 1</h3>
    John Smith
</div>
```

I need to `getText()` only for John Smith not for `<h3>`.

The statement below is return full text Test 1 John Smith:

```
String txtFix = new WebDriverWait(Login.driver, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                (By.cssSelector(".info"))).getText();
```

Is it possible to get somehow only John Smith using css selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "classic" problem with selenium since a CSS selector or xpath expression has to always refer to an actual element - you cannot directly get the text node.

What you can do here is to:

- get the `div` element's text
- get the `h3` element's text
- remove the `h3` element's text from the `div` element's text

Implementation:

```
String div = new WebDriverWait(Login.driver, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".info"))).getText();
String h3 = div.findElement(By.tagName('h3')).getText();
String txtFix = div.replace(h3, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get text using following:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".info")).getText();
```

it returns following:

```
Test 1
John Smith
```

If you see properly, after `Test 1`, char `\n` is introduced hence `John Smith` is on another line.

Hence, if you want to retrieve only `John Smith`, it can be achieved using `split` like following:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".info")).getText().split("\n")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;       
       if (jse instanceof WebDriver) {
           String text = jse.executeScript("document.getElementByClassName("info").nextSibling";");
           System.out.println(text);
       }
```